# What causes PERC H310 disk to go into foreign state?

Tags: hardware-raid

I mean in general. Could the disk itself be bad. Did someone fat finger a `dd` command or something and wipe out the partition table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much experience with the H310 but if you want to check the disk (a good idea) :

Try checking the disk's SMART info. I don't trust raid controllers for this, altho I think some Dell iDRAC's & Percs can display a disks SMART info now.

I'd pull the disk, connected it to a normal sata port and then run partedmagic (it has a disk check tool, gsmartcontrol (linux), or crystal disk info (windows). 
I recommend the tool in partedmagic as it will highlight anything out of spec, crystaldisk info may do this *i think*

Comment: What I ended up doing (not sure if correct) is reimport the foreign disk. This worked. I then ran an e2fsck on it. I was seeing SMART errors before the import. I will have to check SMART again

Comment: ok glad you got it working! :-) hope you get all your data off